# Applying css in iframe without using javascript or jquery

Tags: iframe

How can I inject css into iframe content without using javascript or jquery.

Comment: Do you not have access to the pages that you are iframing?

Answer (score 0):

Without direct access to the child page, you cannot modify its style.  If you can, you can modify the style like any other page.  Only the iframe tag itself can be subjected to styling without any javascript.

For styling *with* javascript [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe).

Comment: Thank you so much Neil for ensuring  me about this issue.